# "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" even when .loc is used

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I don't understand why this is happening if I'm using .loc to create the `another_df` dataframe

```
>>> df = DataFrame({'a':range(0,10), 'b':range(10,20), 'c':range(20,30)}, index = range(0,10), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> df
   a   b   c
0  0  10  20
1  1  11  21
2  2  12  22
3  3  13  23
4  4  14  24
5  5  15  25
6  6  16  26
7  7  17  27
8  8  18  28
9  9  19  29
>>> another_df =  df.loc[(df.a>4)&(df.b>14)&(df.c>24),:]
>>> another_df
   a   b   c
5  5  15  25
6  6  16  26
7  7  17  27
8  8  18  28
9  9  19  29
>>> another_df['d'] = 'a random string'
<string>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[(df.a>4)&(df.b>14)&(df.c>24),:]
```

Is returning a view or copy of `df`

use `copy`:

```
df = DataFrame({'a':range(0,10), 'b':range(10,20), 'c':range(20,30)},
               index = range(0,10), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
another_df =  df.loc[(df.a>4)&(df.b>14)&(df.c>24),:].copy()
#                                                    ^
#                                                   here
another_df['d'] = 'a random string'
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify which row is to obtain the value `'a random string'` for the new column, `'d'`.  Or you can give the column a list of elements of length `len(another_df)`:

```
another_df['d']=['hello', 'world', 'hello', 'world', 'hello']
```

Comment: Nop, I dont. This statement is going to assign this value to all rows

Comment: I misunderstood your intentions.  If assigning a single value to an entire row is your goal, then follow piRSquared's answer.